# Curses, end of line broken

Tags: python, python-2.7, ncurses, curses, python-curses

I use [Python curses](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html) to develop an interface. As it is in development, it crashes a lot and throws random errors on either `stdout` or `stderr`.

The output is not formatted properly; an error that should look like:

```
Error in line 100:
Exception foo
called from bar
```

looks like:

```
Error in line 100:
                  Exception foo
                               called from bar
```

So apparently `\n` is not interpreted as it should (looks like it expects `\r`). I deal with that by redirecting `stderr` to file or other terminal, but can it be fixed in code?

**Edit**:

This is a fragment of my code (part of a "wrapper" around curses UI)

```
class CursesUI(object):
#...
def _setup(self):
    stdscr = curses.initscr()
    stdscr.keypad(1)
    curses.noecho()
    curses.cbreak()
    curses.curs_set(0)
    return stdscr

def _restore(self):
    # called on close()
    self._stdscr.keypad(0)
    curses.echo()
    curses.nocbreak()
    curses.curs_set(1)
    curses.endwin()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you aren't using `curses.wrapper`

Compare

```
class MyApp:
    def __init__(self, stdscr):
        raise Exception('Arggh')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    curses.wrapper(MyApp)        # This will print your error properly
    # MyApp(curses.initscr())    # This gives the behavior you see
```

The example you posted doesn't show how `_setup` and `_restore` are called. You must be sure that the `close` or `_restore` method is called **before** the traceback is printed using a `try:... finally:...` block.

```
class CursesUI(object):
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self._stdscr = self._setup()
            self.main()
        finally:
            self._restore()

    def main(self):
        curses.napms(500)
        raise Exception('Arggh')
```

Using your `_setup` and `_restore` methods, this prints the traceback properly.

Edit:

As for expecting carriage returns, you are correct `\n` is interpreted as moving down one column and `\r` returns to the line start. So if you are manually printing you could use `sys.stdout.write('msg\r\n')` However I assume you just want to properly read errors when your program exits on a crash.

Edit Again:
Updated the wrapper example to match your posted example.

Comment: I am using a wrapper already. I don't want to emit `\r\n` manually because the code should be compatible both with POSIX and Windows

Comment: @JakubM. Are you using pdcurses or something else? Curses itself is POSIX only and `\r\n` shouldn't limit platform. Also, iff you are using a wrapper, then it isn't properly calling `curses.endwin()`. Can you post a minimal example that prints improperly using the wrapper?

Comment: I edited the question and added wrapper calls. I didn't add the ill-formatted output cause it produces veery long lines and SO didn't display them properly